# Alert view takes very long to pop up

Tags: ios, web-services, thread-safety

After posting the data to the json web service, i need to alert the user whether the data was saved successfully or not. I don't have any issues with this, but after getting the response "Data saved successfully" in the log, the view takes very long(almost 40-50 seconds) to display the alert view. Can anyone help me to get the alert view as soon as i get the response within few seconds? Here's what i did

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some url"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody: requestData];
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
            if(error || !data)
            {
                NSLog(@"JSON Data not posted!");
                [activity stopAnimating];
                UIAlertView *alertMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Data not saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertMessage show];
            }
            else
            {
                [activity startAnimating];
                NSLog(@"JSON data posted! :)");
                NSError *error = Nil;
                NSJSONSerialization *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                NSLog(@"Response is %@", jsonObject);

                NSString *code = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"Code"];
                NSLog(@"Code value = %@", code);
                if([code intValue] == 0)
                {
                    [activity stopAnimating];
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Data updated!" message:@"Entered data above has been saved in the database successfully." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                }
                else
                {
                    [activity stopAnimating];
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Data not saved" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                }

            }

        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are calling the alert view code from a separate thread. All UI elements need to be handled from the main thread.

In your case, you should change to following,

```
[activity performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Or you can do this with GCD,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [activity stopAnimating];
    UIAlertView *alertMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Data not saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertMessage show];
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Interesting that it's able to lock the user interaction immediately, but not update the UI. Thank the lord for that dispatch_async, though. I ran into troubles trying to dislay a custom alert explaining why we need push notifications and asking permission to request permission before using the system prompt, but with iOS 10's UNUserNotificationSettings thing, you fetch the settings asynchronously, so triggering my prompt from within there triggered the alert from a background thread. That was odd.

Answer (score 1):

You should do all UI interactions inside the block in main thread. Just use the below code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [activity stopAnimating];
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Data updated!" message:@"Entered data above has been saved in the database successfully." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
});
```